# Server version inicia excepción con sqldataclient c#

Tags: c#

Estoy haciendo conexión a base de datos con sql data cliente , sin embargo en ocaciones me da error de server versión , algo como esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El método que utilizo es este , cabe aclarar que el método funciona en otros llamados pero no entiendo porque pasa a veces y como solucionarlo:

```
public async Task<List<List<Respuesta>>> SelectFromDatabaseGeneric(ConexionSQL con, string consulta)
        {


            List<List<Respuesta>> resultados = new List<List<Respuesta>>();



            try
            {
                using (var conexion = new SqlConnection("Server=" + con.Servidor + ";Initial Catalog=" + con.BD + ";User Id=" + con.Usuario + ";Password=" + con.Password + ";MultipleActiveResultSets=True;"))
                {



                    await conexion.OpenAsync();

                    using (var comando = new SqlCommand(consulta, conexion))
                    {
                        var reader = await comando.ExecuteReaderAsync();


                        foreach (var item in reader.Cast<DbDataRecord>())
                        {
                            List<Respuesta> columnas = new List<Respuesta>();

                            for (int i = 0; i < item.FieldCount; i++)
                            {
                                if (item.GetValue(i) != null)
                                {
                                    Respuesta celda = new Respuesta
                                    {
                                        Columna = item.GetName(i),
                                        Valor = item.GetValue(i)
                                    };

                                    columnas.Add(celda);
                                }
                            }

                            resultados.Add(columnas);
                        }

                    }
                }


                return resultados;

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                List<Respuesta> columnas = new List<Respuesta>();

                Respuesta celda = new Respuesta
                {
                    Columna = "error",
                    Valor = e.ToString()
                };

                columnas.Add(celda);

                resultados.Add(columnas);

                return resultados;
            }


        }
```

El resultado de la consulta en sql es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: cuando falla, puedes ver que `consulta` estas ejecutando? porque el error parece que se relaciona con lo que estas queriendo ejecutar

Comment: Correcto ya revise la consulta y esta bien. El problema se da desde que se crea la instancia del SQLConnection. Algunas veces detecta bien el server versioon y otras no

Comment: identifica en que llamado en especifico causa el error me refiero a los parametros de consulta

Comment: select count(id) as conteo from xxxxxxxx where destinatario='rviquez@xxx.cr' and status='false'

Comment: En esa es cuando falla @MiguelZarate

Comment: Ejecuta esa consulta en el SQL Server y mira lo que resulta

Comment: @fredyfx  me devuelve un conteo en 0.

Comment: Lo extraño es que solo con esa consulta da el error

Comment: que es eso de `servidor publicado`, y porque la ip es un 201.204.xx, eso no parece ser una ip de una red local. No deberias exponer NUNCA el sql server en un hosting a intenet

Comment: pero usas Azure o no lo usas ? Si estas desarrollando se supone que la db la tengas local, despues si estas creando servicios el connection string es el que obtengas desde el panel de configuracion de Sql Azure. Pero te contradices, dices quee s la unica forma, pero despues que no quieres usarlo.

Comment: Buscando en la documentación de microsoft encontre esto : https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.openasync?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Poniendole esto en la cadena de conexión: Context Connection=true  me da otro error el cual puedo corregir de 2 maneras sacar el sqlconnection del using o ponerle Open() en lugar de OpenAsync!!!! Que cosas!!!